# how to fill column value from another table if value exist in column then assign a string if not assign other string using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Now I have two different data frames as the below for an example the first table is `df1` and the second table is `df2`
Have table here with two columns and the `Col1` is empty

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Col1           |     Col2         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |         7        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

and here's another dataframe with one column

```
|---------------------|
|      col3          |
|---------------------|
|          5          |
|---------------------|
|          6          |
|---------------------|
|          7          |
|---------------------|
```

So Now I want to fill `Col1` in the first table with values for example, I want to make the result like this

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Col1           |     Col2         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Value1      |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Value1      |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Value1      |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Value1      |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Value2      |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Value2      |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Value2      |         7        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I mean that I need to create something the below code:

```
for i in df1.Col2
   if: df1.Col2.values = df2.Col3.values
        #the Col1 value in df1 will be "value2"

   else
       #the Col1 value in df1 will be "value1"
```

So any know how can I solve this using pandas?

Comment: Use `df1['Col1'] = np.where(df1.Col2.isin(df2.Col3), "value2", "value1")`

Comment: @jezrael solved thanks alot